# Load segment of page with jquery and run code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the situation:
I've got a mainpage and i've got multiple partial pages,
I use Jquery to .load these partial pages into the mainpage as navigation.

Example:
$(mainpage).load("partpage .pageContent";
As you can see i don't load the full page, just a segment.

Here's the question: 
How do i run anything within the partial page's script tag?
I've googled for the answer and haven't been able to find an answer.
It does not run the code even when i put it into the segment i am loading at that moment.

Thanks,
G3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, so you have a main page and you want to load html into it as the user navigates. And these partial pages hava javascript that needs to be executed when included. Did i get that right ?

Here is the main page.

home.html

```
...
<body>

<script>

   //loading partial file via AJAX
   // would be triggered by a user clicking on a link
   var request = $.ajax({
      url: "segments/segment_a.html",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html"
   });

   request.done(function(partial_html){
      $('.page').html(partial_html)
   });

<div class='page'></div>

</script>

main page content

</body>

...
```

Now to the segment file in the server:
/segments/segment_a.html

```
<div class='segment' id='segment_a'>

       <script>
          // script that should run when segment_a is loaded onto main page
       </script>

       <h2> Segment A </h2>

       <p> some text </p>

</div>
```

Once the segment page is loaded the javascript within the 'script' tags at the very top should be executed.

Comment: You're spot on, i'm gonna try this. Thanks! :D

Comment: I forgot to mention, i have 2 divs in my segment pages. 1 for the header of the page and 1 for the actual content, any idea's on how to implement that?

Comment: You can place that and any content in each segment file within the 'div' with the class 'segment'. That is if you follow the example layout i used. You can replace the contents of the segment_a.html with anything you want.

Comment: Accepted as answer, i couldn't split my content the way i wanted to but i decided it looks better together anyway :) Thanks for the answer though! :D